# Handsontable change cell color with respect to the next cell of next column

Tags: jquery, cell, background-color, handsontable

I have a `handsontable` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#example1grid").handsontable({
    colHeaders: [],        
  });

  var data = [
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 0, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30,35, 12, 13]
  ];

  $("#example1grid").handsontable("loadData", data);   

});
```

What I need is:

My column B having values : **10,20,30** and column C -> **11,0,35**

If **value in cell C > value in cell B then background-color of cell B should be red** else **background-color of cell cell B should be green**.

**So in Result Cell B with values 10,30 -> RED and 20 -> Green**

Check the fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/ygfnR/357/)

Comment: you can write cellRenderer function for handson table. you can do conditional formatting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#example1grid").handsontable({
        colHeaders: ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],        
      });

      var data = [
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
      ];

      $("#example1grid").handsontable("loadData", data);   
        //$('td').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
    Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRender', function(){
      var f = $('.htCore').find('tbody tr td:nth-child(2)');
      var s = $('.htCore').find('tbody tr td:nth-child(3)');
         f.each(function(i,v){
         if (s.eq(i).text() > $(v).text()) {
           $(v).css({'background':'red'});
         } else {
           $(v).css({'background':'green'});
         }
         });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ra8gwa7/1/

or :

```
  $("#example1grid").handsontable("loadData", data);   
    //$('td').css('background-color', 'red');
});
Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRender', function() {
var d = this;
var col1 = d.getDataAtCol(1);
var col2 = d.getDataAtCol(2);
$.each(col1,function(i,v){

 if (col2[i] > v ) {
  $(d.getCell(i,1)).css({'background':'red'});
 } else {
 $(d.getCell(i,1)).css({'background':'green'});
 }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L77wjmk9/

Comment: spot on. Thanks a lot buddy!!

Comment: Good solution but be careful since modifying the DOM this way goes against the Handsontable way of doing things. For example, if you ever freeze these columns, they are no longer in the `.htCore` and will not get the color applied. Another way of doing this is by applying a `customRenderer` to your columns where you check values and apply css rules directly to the rendered TD.

Comment: ok buddy. @ZekeDroid can you create a fiddle using `customRenderer ` and post as an answer? It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @ZekeDroid how about the second way? ^

Comment: yeah sorry, i realized the comment should be followed by the fiddle. I'll work on that now :D

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment about a non DOM manipulating solution, here is one using native Handsontable methods:

http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/2ra8gwa7/2/

The important bit is the renderer. When trying to apply different rendering behavior, rather than manipulating the DOM after render, you should use these custom renderers:

```
function colorRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

            // get reference to data
    var data = instance.getData();
    // grab the value of the current row at the column we want to compare to
    var valueAtC = data[row][2];
    if (valueAtC > value) {
        td.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
        td.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }

    return td;
};
```

As you can see, all we have to do is apply this renderer to the `B` column only and so whenever any cell on that column is rendered, it'll check for the value at that same row, but on column `C`. Then we apply the changes to the `td` directly which ensures all Handsontable methods have access to THIS DOM element and not a manually manipulated one!

Comment: the colors seem to not update when a new value is added

Comment: open up the console and see if there are any bugs? I'm seeing it work just fine. maybe browser type? are you trying off of my fiddle or your code?

Comment: jsfiddle is broken , had some leftover sessiondata, the new jsfiddle is bugy especially the session save